# no matching function for call to boost::condition_variable::wait

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, boost-bind

This is my scenario

```
boost::condition_variable        _condition;
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(_mutex);
boost::detail::atomic_count      _count;
.........
_condition.wait(&lock, boost::bind(std::less<int>(), boost::ref(_count), max));
```

Getting error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>*, boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, std::less<int>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::reference_wrapper<boost::detail::atomic_count>, boost::_bi::value<short unsigned int> > >)'
```

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`condition_variable::wait()` accepts a [single argument](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable.wait)

> `void wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>& lock)`

or the two argument case with a [predicate type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable.wait_predicate)

> `template<typename predicate_type> void wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>& lock, predicate_type pred)`

In either case, the first argument is a reference not a pointer as in your example.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I am getting undefined reference error. I am using QtCreator under Windows. What library I need to use ? `-lboost_thread` ?

Comment: and when compiling with VS Compiler getting `fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib'`

Comment: @Neel Basu , ensure that you added boost/lib path to linker paths (Properties-->Linker-->Additional library directories).

Comment: There is no `Properties` in QtCreator I am not using Visual Studio ?